# Add separator to string with regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string

Suppose the string is:

```
string x = "0000000000";
```

I want to add a seperator like `"."` after each 3 character group starting from the end.

Output should be :

```
0.000.000.000
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the following regex:

```
(\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))
```

And replace with `$1.`

Here is a [RegexStorm demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5Cd)(%3F%3D(%3F%3A%5Cd%7B3%7D)%2B(%3F!%5Cd))&i=0000000000&r=%241.) (see **Context** tab on that page)

```
var rx = new Regex(@"(\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))");
var res = rx.Replace("0000000000", "$1.");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(?=(?:\d{3})+$)
```

You can simply use this and replace by `.`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vH0iN5/13

Answer (score 1):

As a *non*-regex solution, you can use [`Batch`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Batch.cs) from [`MoreLINQ`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) to get equally sized strings and reverse it and combine with [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like;

```
string s = "0000000000";
var group = s.Batch(3, p => new string(p.ToArray())).ToList();
group.Reverse();
var result = string.Join(".", group);
Console.WriteLine(result); // 0.000.000.000
```